# JsonConvert::DeserializeObject erro c++ cli

Tags: json, json.net, c++-cli

I'm trying to open a file and .json already sends it to a Class.
But I get error when doing.

```
ref class CutAnnotationJSon
{

public:

    int index;

    String^ nomeTipo;

    double pontoX1;
    double pontoY1;

    double pontoX2;
    double pontoY2;


    double height;


    int r;
    int g;
    int b;


    int numberCut;

};

ref class PanoramicAnnotationJSon
{

public:

    int index;

    String^ nomeTipo;

    double pontoX1;
    double pontoY1;

    double pontoX2;
    double pontoY2;

    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

};

ref class DadosJSon
{

public:

    List<PanoramicAnnotationJSon^>^ panoramicAnnotation = gcnew List<PanoramicAnnotationJSon^>;

    List<CutAnnotationJSon^>^ cutAnnotation = gcnew List<CutAnnotationJSon^>;

};
```

using

```
DadosJSon^ dadosJSon = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<DadosJSon^>(File::ReadAllText("c:/movie.json"));
```

Error Message:

> ```
> 103  IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "Newtonsoft::Json::JsonConvert::DeserializeObject" matches the argument list:
>         function template "T Newtonsoft::Json::JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<T>(System::String ^value)"
>         function template "T Newtonsoft::Json::JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<T>(System::String ^value, ... cli::array<Newtonsoft::Json::JsonConverter ^, 1> ^converters)"
>         argument types are: (System::String ^)
> ```

I'm using `Newtonsoft::Json::;`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem and I cannot - your code compiles successfully.  Can you give a full [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including all `using namespace` statements?  Also, what version of Json.NET are you using?  And what version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem.  However, you could explicitly select the [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String, JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) overload (which does what you want) via:

```
DadosJSon^ dadosJSon = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<DadosJSon^>(File::ReadAllText("c:/movie.json"), (JsonSerializerSettings ^)nullptr);
```

Passing a `nullptr` value for the settings is equivalent to `JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<DadosJSon^>(File::ReadAllText("c:/movie.json"))`.